# Why are all these QSqlQuery properties returning false?

Tags: qt, sqlite, qsqlquery

I have setup a database like this, and confirmed that records are being added and read successfully from a table called "person":

```
    db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setHostName("localhost");
    db.setDatabaseName("testDatabase.db");
    if (db.open()){

        checkTableExists("person"); //see below

        QSqlQuery query;
        query.exec("create table person (id int primary key, "
                       "firstname varchar(20), lastname varchar(20))");
        query.exec("insert into person values(101, 'Danny', 'Young')");
        query.exec("insert into person values(107, 'Christine', 'Holand2')");
        query.exec("insert into person values(103, 'Lars', 'Gordon')");
        query.exec("insert into person values(104, 'Roberto', 'Robitaille')");
        query.exec("insert into person values(105, 'Maria', 'Papadopoulos')");

        checkTableExists("person"); //see below

        QSqlQuery query2("SELECT lastname FROM person");
             while (query2.next()) {
                 QString lastname = query2.value(0).toString();
                 qDebug()<<lastname;
             }

    }else{ //handle problem }
```

Now to learn more about the various properties on QSqlQuery, I made this function which I'm only using to debug at the moment:

```
bool checkTableExists(QString tablename)const{
    QString sqlQuery = QString("SELECT name FROM testDatabase.db WHERE type =:table AND name = :tablename ");
    QSqlQuery query;
    bool prepare=query.prepare(sqlQuery);
    query.bindValue(":table", "table");
    query.bindValue(":tablename", tablename);
    bool isExec=query.exec();

    qDebug()<<"prepare: "<<prepare;
    qDebug()<<"exec: " << isExec;
    qDebug()<<"first: " << query.first();
    qDebug()<<"isSelect: " << query.isSelect();
    qDebug()<<"isValid: " << query.isValid();
    qDebug()<<"isActive: " << query.isActive();
    qDebug() << "next:" << query.next();
    qDebug()<< "nextResult: "<<query.nextResult();
    qDebug()<<"numRowsAffectd: "<<query.numRowsAffected();

    return query.next();

}
```

When I run the above, I get:

```
prepare:  false 
exec:  false 
first:  false 
isSelect:  false 
isValid:  false 
isActive:  false 
next: false 
nextResult:  false 
numRowsAffectd:  -1 
prepare:  false 
exec:  false 
first:  false 
isSelect:  false 
isValid:  false 
isActive:  false 
next: false 
nextResult:  false 
numRowsAffectd:  -1 
"Young" 
"Holand" 
"Gordon" 
"Robitaille" 
"Papadopoulos" 
"Holand2"
```

Both before and after the creation of the table, none of these properties return true, why is that?

Comment: Everything after exec() will be a subsequent error of exec() failing. Check query.lastError() after the failing exec().

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld what's strange is that the query is not failing, it is in fact returning expected results. So why would exec() report failure?

Comment: The second query in checkTableExists() returns the expected results? It doesn't look like that to me, also I don't think the query syntax is correct (SELECT from .db file?). The queries in the first function might succeed just fine, but they don't have any relation to what you print in checkTableExists() (different query objects).

Comment: Well, check lastError() in checkTableExists(), after the exec()

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld you are correct, the error was returning a syntax problem with the query. Which is strange since the syntax is verbatim what I've seen in several other places for checking if a table already exists.